# WIN32 - How can I query for an image's metadata?

Tags: winapi

I want to know how can I query for metada of an image that I loaded with LoadImage. For example, how do I go about querying its demensions?

Comment: [GetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject).

Comment: You should define explicitly what you mean by "metadata", it it's "just" the dimension, or like full image metadata (exif, xmp, etc.). In the latter case, WIC is a Windows API that can read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-about-metadata (and has nothing to do with LoadImage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) with [`BITMAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmap).

I create a sample with `LoadImage`:

```
HWND background = CreateWindow("STATIC", "background", SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 200, 200, 300, 300, hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
HBITMAP hBmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, "test.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 100, 100, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SendMessage(background, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBmp);
```

This sample shows an image:

[image]

Then I get the image information through `GetObject`:

```
BITMAP bitmapInfo;
GetObject(hBmp, sizeof bitmapInfo, &bitmapInfo);
```

Then you can view the specific information of the image through the returned [`BITMAP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmap)structure.

It works for me:

[image]